# which backend technology to use to prevent cors

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm setting up a new contact formular with React. I have 0 backend knowledge. Users should be able to fill in their data in the contact formular and click "Submit". after submit has been triggered, their contact data should be sent to my slack channel via ifttt.

problem: I get the cors error. with my little knowledge i have, i guess that is because i let the website handle the request to the third party ifttt, and not a server.

am i right that a little node.js backend would help me out?
i have zero node.js knowledge. which technology would be the easiest to accomplish that?

in the frontend part i'm just using fetch to trigger the POST http request.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with javascript then gets hands-on node js and it has a very big community. As well as you can install the "cors" library from npm to avoid Cross-Origin Requests.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should serve your react app through a nodejs server. Then when your user submits the form, you can call ifttt from your node server, that won't trigger any cors error (actually you will not need cors anymore).

I don't know ifttt, you should start by checking their rest api to see what you can do (you will surely need to login through an oauth process or through their library with an API key)

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();

app.use(cors());
```

Comment: this won't work since the react code is not hosted by the target server

Comment: you need to integrate your react and node app via axios or HTTP request

Comment: whether it's through axios or any other requesting mean, the browser won't let you post into a domain that is not the one the form was loaded from. if a get request is accepted by ifttt this could work, but obviously he needs a post request since he has the cors issue

Comment: The only way it could work is to have his react app hosted by slack, maybe it's possible... as I said in my answer, I don't know this api

Comment: hey guys, thanks for your help. is this what i need? https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-deploy-a-react-app-with-an-express-server-on-heroku-32244fe5a250